# Is it possible to execute Step Concurrency for AWS EMR through AWS STEP FUNCTION without Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

This is my Scenario, I'm trying to create 4 AWS EMR clusters, where each cluster will be assigned with 2 jobs in it, so it'll be like 4 clusters with 8 jobs orchestrated using Step Function.

My Flow should be like:

4 Clusters will start at the same time running 8 jobs parallelly, where each cluster will run 2 jobs parallelly.

Now, recently AWS has launched this feature to run 2 (or) more jobs in a single cluster simultaneously using **StepConcurrencyLevel** in EMR to reduce the runtime of the cluster, which can be performed using EMR console, AWS CLI (or) even through AWS lambda.

But, I want to execute this process of launching 2 (or) more jobs parallelly in a single cluster using AWS Step Function with it's state machine language like the format referred here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-emr.html

I've tried referring many sites to execute this process, where I'm getting solution for doing it through the console (or) through boto3 format in AWS lambda, but I couldn't find the solution on executing this through Step Function itself...

Is there any Solution for this!?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: You can do spark submit via livy api also, any strong reason for not using it?

Comment: Yeah.. I have this requirement to execute this whole process only using aws emr clusters through state machine language of step function...

Comment: that doesnt anwser anything. Also, try single EMR cluster with auto scale instead of 4 clusters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I went through few more sites and found a solution for my issue...

The issue I faced was StepConcurrencyLevel, where I can add it using AWS Console (or) through AWS CLI (or) even through Python using BOTO3... But I was expecting a solution using State Machine Language and I found one...

All we have to do is while creating our cluster using the State Machine Language we have to specify the StepConcurrencyLevel in it like 2 (or) 3, where the default is 1. Once it's been set then create 4 steps under that cluster and run the State Machine.

Where the cluster will recognize the number of concurrency been set and will run the Steps accordingly.

**My Sample Process:**

-> **JSON Script of my orchestration**

```
 {
  "StartAt": "Create_A_Cluster",
  "States": {
    "Create_A_Cluster": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:createCluster.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "Name": "WorkflowCluster",
        "StepConcurrencyLevel": 2,
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Description",
            "Value": "process"
          },
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "filename"
          },
          {
            "Key": "Owner",
            "Value": "owner"
          },
          {
            "Key": "Project",
            "Value": "roject"
          },
          {
            "Key": "User",
            "Value": "user"
          }
        ],
        "VisibleToAllUsers": true,
        "ReleaseLabel": "emr-5.28.1",
        "Applications": [
          {
            "Name": "Spark"
          }
        ],
        "ServiceRole": "EMR_DefaultRole",
        "JobFlowRole": "EMR_EC2_DefaultRole",
        "LogUri": "s3://prefix/prefix/log.txt/",
        "Instances": {
          "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps": true,
          "InstanceFleets": [
            {
              "InstanceFleetType": "MASTER",
              "TargetSpotCapacity": 1,
              "InstanceTypeConfigs": [
                {
                  "InstanceType": "m4.xlarge",
                  "BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice": 90
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "InstanceFleetType": "CORE",
              "TargetSpotCapacity": 1,
              "InstanceTypeConfigs": [
                {
                  "InstanceType": "m4.xlarge",
                  "BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice": 90
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 5,
          "MaxAttempts": 1,
          "BackoffRate": 2.5
        }
      ],
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "Next": "Fail_Cluster"
        }
      ],
      "ResultPath": "$.cluster",
      "OutputPath": "$.cluster",
      "Next": "Add_Steps_Parallel"
    },
    "Fail_Cluster": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
      "Parameters": {
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:919490798061:rsac_error_notification",
        "Message.$": "$.Cause"
      },
      "Next": "Terminate_Cluster"
    },
    "Add_Steps_Parallel": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "Step_One",
          "States": {
            "Step_One": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync",
              "Parameters": {
                "ClusterId.$": "$.ClusterId",
                "Step": {
                  "Name": "The first step",
                  "ActionOnFailure": "TERMINATE_CLUSTER",
                  "HadoopJarStep": {
                    "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
                    "Args": [
                      "spark-submit",
                      "--deploy-mode",
                      "cluster",
                      "--master",
                      "yarn",
                      "--conf",
                      "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true",
                      "--conf",
                      "maximizeResourceAllocation=true",
                      "--conf",
                      "spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true",
                      "--py-files",
                      "s3://prefix/prefix/pythonfile.py",
                      "s3://prefix/prefix/pythonfile.py"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              "Retry": [
                {
                  "ErrorEquals": [
                    "States.ALL"
                  ],
                  "IntervalSeconds": 5,
                  "MaxAttempts": 1,
                  "BackoffRate": 2.5
                }
              ],
              "Catch": [
                {
                  "ErrorEquals": [
                    "States.ALL"
                  ],
                  "ResultPath": "$.err_mgs",
                  "Next": "Fail_SNS"
                }
              ],
              "ResultPath": "$.step1",
              "Next": "Terminate_Cluster_1"
            },
            "Fail_SNS": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
              "Parameters": {
                "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:919490798061:rsac_error_notification",
                "Message.$": "$.err_mgs.Cause"
              },
              "ResultPath": "$.fail_cluster",
              "Next": "Terminate_Cluster_1"
            },
            "Terminate_Cluster_1": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:terminateCluster.sync",
              "Parameters": {
                "ClusterId.$": "$.ClusterId"
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "StartAt": "Step_Two",
          "States": {
            "Step_Two": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep",
              "Parameters": {
                "ClusterId.$": "$.ClusterId",
                "Step": {
                  "Name": "The second step",
                  "ActionOnFailure": "TERMINATE_CLUSTER",
                  "HadoopJarStep": {
                    "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
                    "Args": [
                      "spark-submit",
                      "--deploy-mode",
                      "cluster",
                      "--master",
                      "yarn",
                      "--conf",
                      "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true",
                      "--conf",
                      "maximizeResourceAllocation=true",
                      "--conf",
                      "spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true",
                      "--py-files",
                      "s3://prefix/prefix/pythonfile.py",
                      "s3://prefix/prefix/pythonfile.py"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              "Retry": [
                {
                  "ErrorEquals": [
                    "States.ALL"
                  ],
                  "IntervalSeconds": 5,
                  "MaxAttempts": 1,
                  "BackoffRate": 2.5
                }
              ],
              "Catch": [
                {
                  "ErrorEquals": [
                    "States.ALL"
                  ],
                  "ResultPath": "$.err_mgs_1",
                  "Next": "Fail_SNS_1"
                }
              ],
              "ResultPath": "$.step2",
              "Next": "Terminate_Cluster_2"
            },
            "Fail_SNS_1": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
              "Parameters": {
                "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:919490798061:rsac_error_notification",
                "Message.$": "$.err_mgs_1.Cause"
              },
              "ResultPath": "$.fail_cluster_1",
              "Next": "Terminate_Cluster_2"
            },
            "Terminate_Cluster_2": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:terminateCluster.sync",
              "Parameters": {
                "ClusterId.$": "$.ClusterId"
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "ResultPath": "$.steps",
      "Next": "Terminate_Cluster"
    },
    "Terminate_Cluster": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:terminateCluster.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "ClusterId.$": "$.ClusterId"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

In this script (or) AWS Step Function's State Machine Language, While creating the cluster I've mentioned the StepConcurrencyLevel as 2 and added 2 spark jobs as Steps below the cluster.

When I ran this script in Step Function, I was able to orchestrate the cluster and steps to run 2 steps concurrently in a cluster without directly configuring it in AWS EMR console (or) through AWS CLI (or) even through BOTO3.

I just used the State Machine Language to execute the orchestration of running 2 steps concurrently in a single cluster under AWS Step Function without any help from other services like lambda or livy API or BOTO3 etc...

This is how the Flow Diagram Looks:
[AWS Step Function Workflow for concurrent step execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0jSQ.png)

To be more accurate on where I inserted the StepConcurrencyLevel in the above State Machine Language is here:

```
"Create_A_Cluster": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:createCluster.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "Name": "WorkflowCluster",
    "StepConcurrencyLevel": 2,
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "Description",
        "Value": "process"
      },
```

Under **Create_A_Cluster**.

Thank You.

Comment: Hi, I have a used case where I need to run concurrent steps with the help of SF. Therefore, I would like to know few things: 1. What is the impacts on cluster, if there is a delay in step execution from that state of the SF 2. Have you faced any major blockers  3. What are pros and cons of doing it with the help of SF

Comment: Actually, we do have some cons like the concurrent step execution doesn't run 2 steps simultaneously with the cluster config we have... It accelerates the first step with the given config and the second step is running but not in full cluster capacity. Then, regarding the communication between SF and EMR cluster is good there's no problem in it...

Comment: @NaveenB   "ActionOnFailure": "TERMINATE_CLUSTER", is working for you ? I get error validation exception when i try this option.

Comment: @NaveenB what happens if step1 is still running and step2 has failed will step2 terminate_cluster_2 waits until step 1 is complete or straight away terminates the cluster ?

Comment: @sriharikalicharanTummala It will wait, because we are running those steps under parallel Type so once both steps under parallel is done then the cluster will terminate